# SQLiteDataBase Create

Tags: android, sqlite

in SQLiteDataBase , what is the duty NULL on this Line?

```
myDataBase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("myDB.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for doing additional operations on the query results. The reason of passing null is you want the standard SQLiteCursor behaviour

[SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory.html)

Answer (score 2):

Read official guideline about [**`openOrCreateDatabase`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler))  .

```
SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase (String path, 
                    SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, 
                    DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)
```

**`errorHandler`** value may be **null**.

> The third parameter is a reference for CursorFactory object. This
>   object will be used to create custom Cursor objects. This value is passed as null reference, since there are no needs for a custom Cursor object (You will receive a default Cursor object when reading from database).

Courtesy goes to [**`Basic Android Database`**](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/03/basic-android-database.html).